# Django @login_required redirects to home page

Tags: django

I have an issue with the below code. When I login below and try to submit the create.html template it redirects me to Home page (via home function in views and record is not saved in database). When i remove @login_required and directly navigate to /products/create , the record is saved down in database. I am confused why this is happening. Any assistance will be appreciated

I removed (@login_required) and directly navigated to /products/create and it works perfectly. However whenever I login and then use /products/create the record is not saved in database

Create.html

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}

{%block content%}

{%if error%}
{{error}}
{%endif%}

<h2> Create </h2>
{% csrf_token %}
<form  action="create"  method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

{% csrf_token %}
Title:
<br/>
<input type="text"  name = "title"/>
<br/><br/> 
Body:
<br/>
<input type="textbox" name = "body"/>
<br/><br/>
URL:
<br/>
<input type="text" name = "url"/>
<br/><br/> 
<input type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary" value = "Add Product"/>

</form>
{%endblock%}
```

Main url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from products import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/',    admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),
    path('products/',include('products.urls')),
    path('',views.home,name='home'),]
```

Sub project url.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('create',views.create,name='create'),]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import path
from .models import Product
from django.utils import timezone

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'products/home.html')

@login_required    
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['title'] and request.POST['body'] and request.POST['url']:
            product=Product()
            product.title = request.POST['title']
            product.body = request.POST['body']
            product.url = request.POST['url']
            product.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
            product.save()
            return render(request,'products/test.html',{'error':'all conditions checked'})
        else:
            return render(request,'products/test.html',{'error':'all conditions not checked'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'products/create.html',{'error':'post method not checked'})
```

For reference

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    body = models.TextField()
    url = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    votes_total = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def summary(self):
        return self.body[:100]

    def pub_date_pretty(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')
```

*** Login function ***

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       user =     auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request,'accounts/login.html',{'error':'incorrect username or password'})

    else:
           return render(request,'accounts/login.html')
```

Comment: Have you added any redirect url when using `@login_required` ? Have you tried to create without log in the user?

Comment: The issue is most likely related to your login code. `login_required` just checks if user is authenticated and if not redirects user to login url.

Comment: The Login code simply redirects to home. However, once user is logged in and user navigates to /products/create and fills the template above it doesn't save the data i.e. it doesn't trigger "create" function above. For your reference i have put the login function above

Comment: However if i navigate directly to products/create without logging in it does trigger "create" function above.

Comment: No I have not created any redirect page. Also when I remove the @login_required and directly navigate to /products/create without logging in then I am able to save the record. However, if i login and then navigate to /products/create it lets me fill the form but doesnt save the record and directs me straight to home. i.e. it doesnt trigger "create" function , even though form above is directed to "create" function on submission

Comment: I reviewed my question @Borut and your answer above. I have been able to remediate the issue based on your approach. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it